# list field value need to be visible in webpart

Tags: list, web-part

I have a list A with field SAP (radiobutton datatype). It has 3 values SAP-FSL, SAP NXP and both. I need to display these 3 values in webpart as radiobutton provided in image. It will be dynamic, in future if we want to add new radio control in webpart we just want to add new value in fields SAP. How to achieve this. Please help with c#. Thanks.
[image: List value in webpart]

Answer (score 0):

```
SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)spList.Fields[fieldName];

List<string> fieldList = new List<string>();

foreach (string str in field.Choices)
{
    fieldList.Add(str);
}
```

where spList is SPList object.

**fieldList** contains the choice fields value. Using these values, you can bind your radio-button list.

Comment: Just curious; stopped doing C# a long time ago.. isn't there a map function so you can do ``field.Choices.map(=>str)`` instead of that foreach loop?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, for mapping you can refer https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25442/spfieldchoice-mappings link.

Comment: No I meant the Functional Programming term ``map``, found it in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx

Comment: There is no option like `map`.